# Error in GetUserProfileByName (after August Update)

Tags: infopath, forms-services, sharepoint-enterprise, soap

Last Friday I installed August Update on my SharePoint Server 2010.

In my InfoPath form I get current user account by SOAP request (GetUserProfileByName). 
In Connection settings filed "Parameter  - Account name " is I left blank.
But when I try to show value of current user account I get error (in logs):
"Exception Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown. Can not find user.0x80131600 The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.)"

and current accout name is service account.

If I fill value of Parameter Account name in Connection Settings current user account name is equal value in parameter.

Is it any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'd install the October 2011 cumulative update and try again.

Comment: I fix this problem: in my web.config impersonalization was disable. I turn it on: <identity impersonate="true" />.